# How to parse elements appended by AJAX using casperjs?

Tags: ajax, coffeescript, casperjs

I've been working on a little script using `casperjs` that could parse a simple page with elements appended by submitting an AJAX form. How could I do that?

This doesn't seem to work (coffeescript):

```
getLinks = ->
  links = document.querySelectorAll('a')
  Array::map.call links, (e) ->
    e.getAttribute 'href'

casper = require('casper').create()

casper.start 'somepage', ->
  @fill '#some-form', {text: 'hello'}, true
  # appends an element on success

casper.then ->
  links = @evaluate(getLinks)
  @echo links[0]

casper.run ->
  @exit()
```

EDIT:

Submitting the form using casper follows the action of the form, meaning that it redirects to an empty page with a json response instead of catching it in `ajax:success` like it does when I do it manually via a browser. The form has a `post` method and is overriten in javascript to send an AJAX request and append an element to the DOM on success. I've tried changing `javascriptEnabled` setting, but it is `true` by default.

TL;DR Submitting the form using casper doesn't trigger javascript, while doing it manually (or in browser console) does.

Comment: Which PhantomJS version do you use? Please register to the `resource.error`, `page.error`, `remote.message` and `casper.page.onResourceTimeout` events ([Example](https://gist.github.com/artjomb/4cf43d16ce50d8674fdf#file-2_caspererrors-js)). Maybe there are errors.

Comment: That's better, have you registered to the error events to see if for example some JS couldn't be executed? Also, it's important to know which PhantomJS version you're using.

Comment: Thank you very much. Just started using this today, too rushed to think of proper debugging.

Answer (score 0):

Wow, thank you [@Artjom B.](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1816580/artjom-b)

The issue was the standard phantomjs ssl problem, the site was loading jquery using `https`, subscribing to `resource.error` helped me find that.

The solution was to run `casperjs` with `--ignore-ssl-errors=true` flag.